# river network of germany

Tags: germany

I am looking for any gis file of the river network of Germany or at least Bavaria with some kind of attribute of the order / level of the river to style them according of their "order".
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're interested in does not seem to be available for download from LfU Bayern, but at least they do offer the dataset as WMS:

[Grundlagen Fließgewässer - WMS](https://www.lfu.bayern.de/umweltdaten/geodatendienste/index_wms.htm#Wasser) pointing to:

https://www.lfu.bayern.de/gdi/wms/wasser/grundlagen_fliessgewaesser?